# Can a 50mm2 cable handle 350 amperes?

Tags: cables, ampacity

Can a one meter 50mm<sup>2</sup> cable handle 350 amperes?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Of course the measuring is approximate since the cable is flexed.

Comment: Continuously or for a short while?

Comment: Well everything can handle 350A. The question is for how long it can

Answer (score 2):

No.

Source: https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm

Size 0 wire, area 53.5 mm2: "Maximum amps for power transmission" : 150 A or 245 A (depending on the application) which is less than 350 A.

Comment: The same table says "Maximum amps for chassis wiring" for #0 is 245A, so it clearly depends on how the wire is being used and probably also makes some assumptions about the insulation's temperature rating.

Comment: @Davide Andrea 150 A for power transmission and the they didn't specify the length so..?

Comment: @brhans 245A is still less than 350 A. Therefore, no matter what the intended use, Size 0 wire is not rated for 350 A

Comment: @user331438 Fundamental concept: length is irrelevant to current carrying rating (ampacity). Another fundamental concept: length affects voltage drop, not ampacity.

Comment: Ampacity impacts temperature, which impacts insulation, which limits length.

Comment: @DavideAndrea  https://mon-fourgon-amenage.fr/electricite/section-de-cable

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat "Impacts temperature".  It impacts _heat_, not temperature. At a given current, the temperature is the same, regardless of length. Yes, a longer cable produces more heat, but it also dissipates more heat along a longer length. The two effect balance each other. The result is that the temperature is the same, regardless of length. It's simple thermal engineering.

Comment: Not the downvote, but the OP is not concerned about power transmission but *a one meter 50mm2 cable*, which is a chassis wiring.

Comment: **This totally depends on application**. This question is not answerable as written because application is not known.  Inside a quadcopter is different than inside the walls of a structure.  Duty cycle matters: Welder yes, EVSE hell no. Allowable thermal rating (on wires *and application* matter. 150°C wire inside walls hell no, inside equipment chassis probably.

Comment: @DavideAndrea "The two effect balance each other. The result is that the temperature is the same, regardless of length. It's simple thermal engineering. " Reality is not so simple. It may be true for medium cable length but not for very short or long cables. The airflow will change heat transfer a lot. The material and thickness of cable insulation has a large effect on temperature.

Comment: @DavideAndrea "Donvoting the correct answer doesn't make YOUR cable carry more current than physic laws allow."  I swear it wasn't me I guess, who locked the question is the responsible, I appreciate the time and effort you have given to my question by you and all the members that contributed in the comments.

Comment: @DavideAndrea Yes, I also wonder. About the application is for welding, just an information jumper cable uses 1 awg and their ampacity rating is above 400 amps heavy duty.

Comment: Current capacity is temp dependent